# Unable to check in code in Visual studio 2010(TFS 2010)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am working on an Asp.net web application. Since yesterday I am unable to check in my code. But I am able to get latest code, compare files , View history and create work items.

While check in- Neither the error message is displayed nor The file that needs to be checked in is locked.

Suspect:-
The application is written for VS 2010. But,Once I opened it on vs 2012. Later I made necessary changes to the solution file so that It re-opens on VS 2010 again. Can this be the reason why check in is not working? Please let me now if you have any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I often mix check ins between vs 2012 and 2010, this would not have an impact

Comment: Hope my answer help :)

Comment: Have you read the source control output logs ? TFS usually prints an error or warning there.

Comment: After make a research for someone it will be a good thing to say atleast, yes this was the problem or no ...

Comment: @mybirthname- Thank you very much for your reply.I don't have access to the source code from home, I can only check at office on tuesday. Our office is closed on saturday's and sunday's. Monday I am on leave I will update you on tuesday with out fail.Thanks.

Comment: Guys thank you very much for all your responses. I will try your suggestion on tuesday and update you on the same day as soon as possible. Thank you all.

Comment: @brz- Can you please let me know where to find the TFS's output logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lock "Check-in". This is also known as the "antisocial":-). A check-in lock prevents anyone else from committing their changes to that file until you have released the lock. This means that they will be responsible for performing any conflict resolution activities that result. You can place a check-in lock on a file even if somebody has a file checked out with a lock type of "none" i.e. I know you are working on this file but you are not allowed to check in your changes until I have made this important quick fix."

Probably this is the case, someone check out the file after your check out. Check who check out the file and contact with him, this is the best advice which I can give you.

Comment: @mybirthname- Can you please let me know how to do 'lock check in'. when I right click on the file for check-in I don't see this option available.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490760(v=vs.100).aspx check this link hope it helps you. If you think the answer is correct you can accept it.

Comment: @ganesh check the link and tell me if this is enough :)

Comment: @mybirthname- Check in is still not working even after doing 'lock check in'. I think this issue is related to something else. Pls let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: @ganesh You can't check in if some other user make the lock check in. Check if other users check out the file and still not check in. If nobody else check the file out the problem is different

Comment: @mybirthname- Thanks for sending the link. It was helpful for locking files for 'check in'.

Comment: @mybirthname- I am the only person working on this project. My name is displayed as checked out for edit. nobody else has checked out the file.

Comment: @ganesh In this case I don't have any other ideas.